# My code throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException but i think it's ok

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception

here is my code:

```
public class TrainingActivity extends Activity {

private EditText etIn1, etIn2, etDesired;
private TextView prevInput;

int W[][] = new int[2][];
int X[][] = new int[30][];

int w0=0, w1=0, w2=0, p=1, sum=0, clicks=0;

private Button nxtData;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.training_activity);

    View backgroundImage = findViewById(R.id.background);
    Drawable background = backgroundImage.getBackground();
    background.setAlpha(40);

    etIn1= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput1);
    etIn2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etInput2);
    etDesired = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etDesired);

    prevInput = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.prevInput);

    nxtData = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextData);
    nxtData.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int sum = 0;
            ++clicks;

            int intetIn1 = Integer.parseInt(etIn1.getText().toString());
            int intetIn2 = Integer.parseInt(etIn2.getText().toString());
            int intetDesired = Integer.parseInt(etDesired.getText().toString());

            X[clicks-1] = new int[] {intetIn1, intetIn2, 1};

            prevInput.setText("Last Inputs: (" + intetIn1 + ", " + intetIn2 +
                    ", " + intetDesired + ")");

            if(clicks == 1) {
            if(intetDesired == 1) {
                W[0] = new int[] {intetIn1, intetIn2, 1};
                W[1] = W[0];
            } else if(intetDesired == (-1)){
                W[0] = new int[] {-intetIn1, -intetIn2, -1};
                W[1] = W[0];
            }
            } else if(clicks > 1) {                 
                for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
                    sum = sum + W[clicks-1][i] * X[clicks-1][i];
                } if(sum>0 && intetDesired==1) {
                    W[clicks] = W[clicks-1];
                } else if(sum<0 && intetDesired==(-1)) {
                    W[clicks] = W[clicks-1];
                } else if(sum<=0 && intetDesired==1) {
                    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                    W[clicks][i] = W[clicks-1][i] + X[clicks-1][i];
                }
                } else if(sum>=0 && intetDesired==(-1)) {
                    for(int i=0; i<3; i++) {
                        W[clicks][i] = W[clicks-1][i] - X[clicks-1][i];
                    }
                }
            }   

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + clicks, 
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            System.out.println(X[0][0]);

            etIn1.setText("");
            etIn2.setText("");
            etDesired.setText("");

        }
    });


}}
```

and here is the Exception:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=2; index=2
```

the clicks is the number of times that user click the button. at first it's ok but when i try and add some more inputs it crashes. can you tell why this is happening?

Comment: I guess the compiler knows it better than you :)
Why don't you write a JUnit test to check what's wrong?

Comment: i guess you are right bro :D .

Comment: ignore the Toast and system.out part please.

Answer (score 0):

index of array is always less than length as index starts form 0 whereas length from 1 therefore `X[clicks-1]` is causing the problem

Answer (score 0):

What is the initial value of click variable.
Can you post more code related. And for the first time if click is 0 then

```
  X[clicks-1] = new int[] {intetIn1, intetIn2, 1};
```

this says you are store these value at click-1 th position which is not even initialized.. so

```
  int X[] = new int[]{intetIn1, intetIn2, 1};
```

would be better.